# помогите с адаптером

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

В адаптере передаю открытие картинок во ViewPager, но неустраивает только одно, не открываются только те новости у которых 10 и больше картинок, а все остальные работают без вопросов!!! помогите исправить??

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mShowStyle;
    VKPostArray obj;
    VKApiPost p;
    VKApiPhoto vkPhoto;
    ArrayList<String> imgUrls1;
    VKApiUser mainUser;
    Context ctx;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
        super();
        this.obj = posts;
        this.mainUser = user;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mShowStyle = showStyle;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {

        p = obj.get(position);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);

        holder.textlikePost.setText(" " + p.likes_count);
        holder.textrepostPost.setText(" " + p.reposts_count);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        holder.textDatePost.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date(p.date * 1000)));

        VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
        att = p.attachments;

        int i;
        imgUrls1 = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (i = 0; i <= att.size(); i++) {
                vkPhoto = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(i);
                imgUrls1.add(vkPhoto.photo_604);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            holder.mNglContent.setImagesData(imgUrls1);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (mShowStyle == NineGridImageView.STYLE_GRID) {
            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        }}

    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView textPost, news_name, textDatePost, textrepostPost, textlikePost;
        ImageView like, repost ;
        NineGridImageView mNglContent;

        private NineGridImageViewAdapter<String> mAdapter = new NineGridImageViewAdapter<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void onDisplayImage(Context context, ImageView imageView, String s) {
                Picasso.with(context).load(s).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_ab_app).into(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            protected ImageView generateImageView(Context context) {
                return super.generateImageView(context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onItemImageClick(Context context, int position, List<String> list) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullPhoto.class);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, (ArrayList<String>)list);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }catch (Exception e){}
            }
        };

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);

            news_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_name);
            textDatePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
            textPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);

            textlikePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);
            textrepostPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reposts_count);
            like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like);
            repost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_repost);

            mNglContent = (NineGridImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ngl_images);
            mNglContent.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
```

принимаю так:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            ar1 =  getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP);
        }
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractListRandomAccess cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList 
at calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.PostAdapter$PostViewHolder$1$override.onItemImageClick(PostAdapter.java:112) 
at calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.PostAdapter$PostViewHolder$1$override.access$dispatch(PostAdapter.java) 
at calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.PostAdapter$PostViewHolder$1.onItemImageClick(PostAdapter.java:0) 
at com.jaeger.ninegridimageview.NineGridImageView$1.onClick(NineGridImageView.java:167) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: для начала, добавьте в `catch ` хотя бы выведение в лог ошибки. А то кто ж знает, что там у вас происходит при более десяти картинок. Кроме того, сами посты в VK поддердивают до 10 картинок, насколько я знаю. Больше 10 прикрепить нельзя

Comment: Кароче так!!! когда добавил лог в catch при нажатии на картинки меньше 9 штук, лог не показывается и открывается FullPhoto.class, а при 10 и больше, показывается лог и FullPhoto.class не открывается

Comment: вот именно, что какой лог? Что за ошибка выводится в лог? Где ее стактрейс?

Comment: Log.v(TAG, "бла бла"); это и выводит

Comment: ошибку выведите

Comment: так никаких ошибок то и нет!!! просто при новости в 10 картинок и более не открывается FullPhoto.class (ничего не выюивает и т.п), а до 10 окрывается))) не понимаю что за фигня

Comment: Наверное NineGridImageViewAdapter поддерживает только 9 картинок, которые он отображает, а 10 не хочет?

Comment: это происходит **именно потому**, что возникает ошибка, которую вы игнорируете. `}catch (Exception e){}`, что переводится на русский, как `если возникает ошибка типа Exception, сделать {}(ничего)`

Comment: так что надо написать в }catch (Exception e){} что бы ее вычислить не понимаю? 
 
Log.v(TAG, "бла бла"); мне и выдает: "бла бла"и ничего больше

Comment: напишите e.printStackTrace();

Comment: писал...ничего не выводит

Comment: не правда. Такое невозможно. Покажите, куда вы написали.

Comment: }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: добавьте туда же ваше `Log.v(TAG, "бла бла");`, и покажите скриншот лога, где выводится ваше "бла, бла"

Comment: Или проще - уберите вообще try...catch, тогда у вас прилождение упадет с ошибкой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46284/discussion-between-sviter-pro-and-metalurgus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractListRandomAccess cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Означает, что вы пытаетесь в этой строке:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, (ArrayList<String>)list);
```

Ваш `list` привести к `ArrayList`, которым он не является.

Это как если у вас есть некое животное, которое вы пытаетесь использовать, как корову, но оно на самом деле совсем не корова, а черепаха. Поэтому и возникает ошибка попытки использовать один класс в качестве другого.

Чтобы исправить ошибку, вы можете создать `ArrayList` на основе вашего `list`:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, new ArrayList(list));
```